# Create user role restricted to specific CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, capabilities

I am trying to create a role that can create and submit to a CPT only. When I take away edit_post from the role, it revokes the ability to create and edit any of the assigned and registered CPTs as well. I have registered and assigned the edit_CPTs capability to the role as well. So basically, I have this:

```
edit_cpt
edit_cpts
```

and I have taken away

```
edit_posts
```

But once I remove `edit_posts` the role cannot even see the CPTs in the dashboard interface. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to register the CPT with your custom capability, then assign that specific cap to the user.

When passing the arguments to [`register_post_type`](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type), set `capability_type` to your new capability, so the check turns into `'edit_cpts'` instead of `'edit_post'`.

By setting `'capability_type' => [ 'cpt', 'cpts' ]`, 'cpt' will map to 'post' for standard capability checks, so where you'd usually check for 'edit_post' you'll now check for 'edit_cpt'.

When you completely remove the primitive `'edit_posts'` cap from users/roles as you've done, you'll need to add in your new one with [`WP_Role::add_cap()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_role/add_cap/) and check for it with `current_user_can( 'edit_cpts' )`.

Comment: Downvote. The problem with this solution is that it removes default capabilities for admin and editor roles.