# How to allow "Add New" capability of CPT when links to its UI are placed as a submenu?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, user-roles, admin-menu, capabilities

(*Edit:*  going for the "Student" badge, and wondering if anyone out there could up vote this question?)

I answered [a question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/367518/how-do-i-code-access-to-the-built-in-ui-of-a-cpt-when-its-placed-as-submenu-of) about capabilities, but now I'm in need of help on the subject.  And after reviewing [the manual](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/roles-and-capabilities/), I'm even more confused.

<strike>I have two custom post types both fully accessible to Administrators.  I have Subscribers, some having access to one of these CPT's which is a "child" of the first and stores it's parent's ID in its `_adm_id` metadata.  These "special" Subscribers have access to the parent CPT admin table so they can click a link to create child CPT posts of parents with a special status.  Next, the Subscriber is allowed to edit child posts (both its own and those created by others) but only if it is of a particular custom post status.  Lastly, special Subscribers are not allowed to delete posts (or edit deleted posts), not even their own.</strike>

Here's what I've got (working code) ...

```
// Setup custom post types and statuses
add_action('init', function() {
    // Custom Post Types
    register_post_type('adm-cpt', array(
        'label'             => __('Admin Only CPT'),
        'show_ui'           => TRUE,
        'show_in_menu'      => 'my-menu-item',
        'show_in_admin_bar' => FALSE,
        'capability_type'   => 'adm',
        'map_meta_cap'      => TRUE,
        'capabilities' => array(
            'create_posts'  => 'administrator', // Only admin can create, not special Subscribers
        ),
    ));
    register_post_type('sub-cpt', array(
        'label'             => __('Subscriber/Admin CPT'),
        'show_ui'           => TRUE,
        'show_in_menu'      => 'my-menu-item',
        'show_in_admin_bar' => FALSE,
        'capability_type'   => 'sub',
        'map_meta_cap'      => TRUE,
    ));
    // Custom Post Statuses
    foreach(array(
        'adm-childable'     => __('Can Create Children'),
        'sub-editable'      => __('Any Subscriber Can Edit'),
    ) as $slug => $label) {
        register_post_status($slug, array(
            'label'         => _x($label, 'post'),
            'label_count'   => _n_noop($label .' <span class="count">(%s)</span>', $label .' <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ),
            'public'        => TRUE,
        ));
    }
});

// Setup parent page in admin menu
add_action('admin_menu', function() {
    // Add menu item
    if(current_user_can('administrator')
    || current_user_can('special-subscriber')
    ) {
        // Admin menu header
        add_menu_page(
            NULL,
            'CPTs',
            'exist',
            'my-menu-item',
            ''
        );
    }
});

// Set up role
add_action('wp_roles_init', function($wp_roles){
    // Prepare
    $role = 'special-subscriber';
    $caps = array(
        'delete_subs'           => FALSE,   // No trashing ...
        'delete_others_subs'    => FALSE,
        'delete_published_subs' => FALSE,
        'delete_private_subs'   => FALSE,
        'edit_published_subs'   => FALSE,   // And no editing published/private posts ...
        'edit_private_subs'     => FALSE,
        'edit_adms'             => TRUE,    // Allow viewing of adm-cpt table
        'edit_posts'            => TRUE,    // WARNING:  Here's the permission that is causing the problems!
    );
    $name = __('"Special" Subscriber');
    // Update role in database, if needed
    if($wp_roles->get_role($role) === NULL
    || $wp_roles->get_role($role)->capabilities != $caps
    || $wp_roles->roles[$role]['name'] !== $name
    ) {
        $wp_roles->remove_role($role);
        $wp_roles->add_role($role, $name, $caps);
    }
});

// Dynamicly set capabilities
add_action('user_has_cap', function($allcaps, $caps, $args, $user) {
    foreach($caps as $cap) {
        $perm = substr($cap, 0, strrpos($cap, '_'));
        $type = substr($cap, strlen($perm)+1);
        if(in_array($type, array('adm', 'adms')) && in_array('administrator', $user->roles)
        || in_array($type, array('sub', 'subs')) && !empty(array_intersect(array('administrator', 'special-subscriber'), $user->roles))
        ) {
            // Check Subscriber if post is editable
            if(in_array($cap, array('edit_subs', 'edit_others_subs'))
            && in_array('special-subscriber', $user->roles)
            && !in_array('administrator', $user->roles)
            && !empty($args[2])
            &&  (   !in_array(get_post_status($args[2]), array('sub-editable'))
                        && !in_array($_REQUEST['original_post_status'], array('sub-editable', 'auto-draft'))    // Creating
                ||  get_post_status(get_post_meta($args[2], '_adm_id', TRUE)) === 'trash'
                )
            ) {
                $allcaps[$cap] = FALSE;
            }
            // Add the cap
            if(!isset($allcaps[$cap])
            ) {
                $allcaps[$cap] = TRUE;  // All the _adm and _sub capabilities are made available.
            }
        }
    }
    return $allcaps;
}, 10, 4);

// Add stuff to force proper navigation
add_action('post_row_actions', function($actions, $post) {
    // Add link to adm-cpt table entries to create child
    if(get_post_type($post) === 'adm-cpt'
    && get_post_status($post) === 'adm-childable'
    && current_user_can('edit_subs')
    ) {
        $lbl = __('New '). get_post_type_object('sub-cpt')->labels->name;
        $actions['adm-cpt-create-sub-cpt'] = sprintf(
            '<a href="%s" aria-label="%s">%s</a>',
            admin_url('post-new.php?post_type=sub-cpt&adm_id='. $post->ID),
            esc_attr('“'. $lbl .'”'),
            $lbl
        );
    }
    // Return
    return $actions;
}, 10, 2);

// Modify publish metabox
add_action('post_submitbox_misc_actions', function($post) {
    $arr = array();
    switch(get_post_type($post)) {
        case 'adm-cpt':
            $arr = array('adm-childable');
            break;
        case 'sub-cpt':
            $arr = array('sub-editable');
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }
    // Check that parent exists -- Should be in an init hook, but it's prettier here.
    if($_REQUEST['post_type'] === 'sub-cpt'
    &&  (empty($_REQUEST['adm_id']) || get_post_type($_REQUEST['adm_id']) !== 'adm-cpt')
    &&  (empty($post->_adm_id) || get_post_type($post->_adm_id) !== 'adm-cpt')
    ){
        ?><script>window.document.location.replace("<?= admin_url('edit.php?post_type=adm-cpt') ?>")</script><?php
        return;
    }
    // Add custom post statuses
    ?><input type='hidden' name='adm_id' value='<?= $_REQUEST['adm_id'] ?>'><?php
    if(count($arr)) {
        ?><script>
        <?php foreach($arr as $k) { $obj = get_post_status_object($k); ?>
            jQuery("select#post_status").append("<option value=\"<?= $k ?>\"><?= $obj->label ?></option>");
            <?php if(get_post_status($post) == $k) { ?>
                jQuery("#post-status-display").text("<?= $obj->label ?>");
                jQuery("select#post_status").val("<?= $k ?>");
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        </script><?php
    }
    // Display parent -- Informational
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['adm_id'])
    || !empty($post->_adm_id)
    ) {
        $parent_id = $post->_adm_id;
        if(!$parent_id) $parent_id = $_REQUEST['adm_id'];
        ?><div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-adm-cpt">Parent:  <span id="post-status-display"><?= get_the_title($parent_id) ?></span></div><?php
    }
});

// Save parent ID
add_action('save_post_sub-cpt', function($post_id, $post, $update) {
    // Ensure we continue only id a new child is created
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE
    || get_post_type($post_id) !== 'sub-cpt'
    || empty($_REQUEST['adm_id'])
    || get_post_type($_REQUEST['adm_id']) !== 'adm-cpt'
    ) return;
    // Set parent ID
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_adm_id', $_REQUEST['adm_id']);
}, 10, 3);

// Navigation when changed to uneditable
add_action('load-post.php', function(){
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['post'])
    && get_post_type($_REQUEST['post']) === 'sub-cpt'
    && !current_user_can('edit_subs', $_REQUEST['post'])
    ) {
        delete_post_meta($_REQUEST['post'], '_edit_lock');
        wp_redirect('edit.php?post_type=sub-cpt');
        die();
    }
});
```

This issue here is that the special Subscriber is able to edit regular Posts and Comments.  I understand this comes from the `edit_posts` capability, and that capability allows for the editing/creation of **all** post types.  However, removing it prevents special Subscribers from being able to create `sub-cpt` posts, and granting `edit_subs` does not solve the problem.  Neither does setting the `capabilities->create_post=special-subscriber` when registering the child CPT.  I've been able to limit the ability of Subscribers from being able to create `adm-cpt` posts by defining the `capabilities` parameter when registering the post type.  But I don't want special Subscribers to be able to edit/create any other posts other than those of the `sub-cpt` type, and I can't seem to figure out how.

I've found [a Q&A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229319/create-user-role-restricted-to-specific-cpt) related to the subject, but this doesn't seem to work.  The CPT's are mapped to custom capabilities, they exist, and the `user_has_cap` filter dynamically grants each of these capabilities.  I've even tried expressly defining them in the `special-subscriber` role definition.  Anyways, I'm sure the change is simple--*what is it*?

(If you're interested, I have another capability problem.  When a special Subscriber sets the child CPT `post_status` to publish, the post is locked and they are forwarded to `edit.php` but I want the post to unlock and for the viewer to be forwarded to `edit.php?post_type=sub-cpt` just like is done in the `load-post.php` hook of my code, and I can't seem to figure out how.)

**UPDATE**:  I've isolated it down to the placement of the CPT in the menu.  When the CPT is registered as showing the UI using the `register_post_type` option of `show_in_menu=TRUE`, everything works as expected.  But, when the CPT is added as a submenu of an old-fashioned admin menu item, things break.  Adding the UI and hiding it results in the same problems, along with adding a subpage and redirecting it to the UI of the CPT.  Examples:

```
// 1.)  Works as expected if user has every custom capability
add_action('init', function() {
    register_post_type('sub-cpt', array(
        'label'             => __('Subscriber/Admin CPT'),
        'show_ui'           => TRUE,
        'show_in_menu'      => TRUE,    // Take note of this
        'show_in_admin_bar' => FALSE,
        'capability_type'   => 'sub',
        'map_meta_cap'      => TRUE,
    ));
}

// 2.)  Same as #1 with the exception that access to 'post-new.php' when "Add New" button is clicked is prohibited
add_action('init', function() {
    register_post_type('sub-cpt', array(
        'label'             => __('Subscriber/Admin CPT'),
        'show_ui'           => TRUE,
        'show_in_menu'      => 'my-menu-item',  // Take note of this
        'show_in_admin_bar' => FALSE,
        'capability_type'   => 'sub',
        'map_meta_cap'      => TRUE,
    ));
}
add_action('admin_menu', function() {
    add_menu_page(
        'CPT in title bar',
        'CPT in menu',
        'edit_subs',
        'my-menu-item',
        ''
    );
}

// 3.)  Breaks the same as #2
add_action('init', function() {
    register_post_type('sub-cpt', array(
        'label'             => __('Subscriber/Admin CPT'),
        'show_ui'           => TRUE,
        'show_in_menu'      => FALSE,   // Take note of this
        'show_in_admin_bar' => FALSE,
        'capability_type'   => 'sub',
        'map_meta_cap'      => TRUE,
    ));
}
add_action('admin_menu', function() {
    global $submenu;
    add_menu_page(
        'CPT in title bar',
        'CPT in menu',
        'edit_subs',
        'my-menu-item'
    );
    add_submenu_page(
        'my-menu-item',
        get_post_type_object('sub-cpt')->label,
        get_post_type_object('sub-cpt')->label,
        'edit_subs',
        'my-menu-item-sub'
    );
    // Change link
    $url = 'edit.php?post_type=sub-cpt';
    $submenu['my-menu-item'][1][2] = admin_url($url);   // Set URL to view CPT
    unset($submenu['my-menu-item'][0]);             // Remove WP generated menu item
});
```

If, I can get the "Add New" functionality to work with the CPT as a subpage, I think my problem will be solved because the `edit_posts` capability giving me trouble can be specifically mapped to `edit_subs`.  Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean with 'things break'?

Comment: I cannot create a new post of this custom type.  [WP dies](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/includes/menu.php#L341) with the "Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when the special subscriber tries to **Add New** a sub-cpt post, it is denied permission.  However, when the CPT menu is a top-admin-menu, then everything works out fine.  The issue is related to the placement of the CPT's UI menu in the back-end:  if it's top-level (`show_in_menu=TRUE`), all is well; if its a submenu (`show_in_menu='my-menu-item'`), the user can't create the post type unless it has the `edit_posts` permission (even if it has all the `edit_PostType` permissions in the world).  I've been chasing this stupid thing since the 22nd.  Thanks to the pandemic, I haven't had to do much of anything else.  After 12-15 hours each of the 8 days, I finally got this little bugger picked.

This issue had something to do with **post-new.php**, as all works out fine when the CPT is edited under the **post.php** script (which is nearly identical).  The very first thing that **post-new.php** does is call on **admin.php**.  On line [153](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/admin.php#L153), **wp-admin/menu.php** is called in to bat which includes **wp-admin/includes/menu.php** as its [last execution](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/menu.php#L326).  On that **includes/menu.php** file's [line 341](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/includes/menu.php#L341), the `user_can_access_admin_page()` returns `FALSE`, triggering the `do_action('admin_page_access_denied')` hook to be fired and the `wp_die(__('Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.'), 403)` command to kill the whole process.

The `user_can_access_admin_page()` method is defined on [line 2042](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L2042) of the **wp-admin/includes/plugin.php** file.  [Line 2064](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L2064) passed its check in that `get_admin_page_parent()` was empty.  This is followed by [line 2078](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php#L2078) failing its check in that the variable of `$_wp_submenu_nopriv['edit.php']['post-new.php']` is set.  The combined effect of these checks the `FALSE` boolean being returned and WordPress dies.

The closest related script known to me is that of **post.php**, as the **admin.php** process is immediately called and runs in an identical manner, including the calling of `user_can_access_admin_page()`.  Debugging demonstrates that the `user_can_access_admin_page()` is passed in the **post.php** script because, unlike **post-new.php**, none of the `$_wp_submenu_nopriv[____][$pagenow]` flags were set.  So, the question is why this index is being set for **post-new.php** and not set for **post.php**.

The `global $_wp_submenu_nopriv` is first set on [line 71](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/includes/menu.php#L71) of **wp-admin/includes/menu.php**, in which that variable is initialized as an empty array.  If the `current_user_can()` test is not passed on [line 79](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/includes/menu.php#L79), the flag is set on [line 81](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/includes/menu.php#L81).  At that point, the `global $submenu['edit.php']` is initialized to the point of our concern, and contains the array at *index=*10 *("Add New", "edit_posts", "post-new.php")*.  A review of [admin menu positioning](https://whiteleydesigns.com/editing-wordpress-admin-menus/)) reveals this entry is the **Add New** link made by the system for standard WP posts.  The check that occurs tests whether or not the current user has the permission to `edit_posts`.  As the special Subscriber user cannot edit "posts," the check fails and the system breaks.  When I learned this, the race was on to unset the `$submenu['edit.php']['post-new.php']` entry before [line 81](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/includes/menu.php#L81) of **wp-admin/includes/menu.php** was executed.  If one worked backwards from that line into **wp-admin/menu.php**, it would be found that the flag at issue is set on [line 170](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/menu.php#L170) with the execution of `$submenu[$ptype_file][10] = array($ptype_obj->labels->add_new, $ptype_obj->cap->create_posts, $post_new_file)`.  So, the hooks fired between these two points in the code will allow us to interject and unset the flag that has caused me so much strife.

The first function called with an available hook after this setting is `current_user_can('switch_themes')` on [line 185](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/menu.php#L185).  A check in the subsequently called `user_has_cap` for this squirmy flag will occur more times than one can count, so its not really the best hook to use.  Following this, the only direct hooks available are those of `_network_admin_menu`, `_user_admin_menu`, or `_admin_menu` found in **/wp-admin/includes/menu.php** straight away at the very top of [the file](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.4/src/wp-admin/includes/menu.php#L9) (only one of them will fire depending on if the request is for the network administration interface, user administration interface, or neither).  Since calling a filter from an unrelated function is a heck of a round-about way of doing things, I chose to make use of these hooks, like so:

```
add_action('_network_admin_menu', 'pick_out_the_little_bugger');
add_action('_user_admin_menu', 'pick_out_the_little_bugger');
add_action('_admin_menu', 'pick_out_the_little_bugger');
function pick_out_the_little_bugger() {
    // If the current user can not edit posts, unset the post menu
    if(!current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
        global $submenu;
        $problem_child = remove_menu_page('edit.php');  // Kill its parent and get its lineage.
        unset($submenu[$problem_child[2]]);         // "unset" is just too nice for this wormy thing.
    }
}
```

Jeezers this was a shot in the dark and wayyyy to much work for less than a dozen lines of code!  Since I found a bunch of people with this same problem, I [opened a ticket](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/50284#ticket) to modify the WordPress Core.

Comment: thanks for figuring this out!

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out. The only problem i see with this solution is that this creates a considerable amount of notices in php.

Comment: @GDY -- yes, it does, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

After debugging this same problem for an hour I was grateful to find this and realize it is a known bug.  I took a slightly different approach to getting around it.

This bug occurs when the CPT UI is a submenu page, the CPT has custom capabilities or capability type, and the current user does not have 'edit_posts' capability.  I created a custom menu page to contain several custom post types and taxonomies and avoid cluttering the admin menu.  But when the user does not have 'edit_posts' capability I only need to show one or two CPTs so I don't really need the custom menu page.  So to get around the problem, I check if the current user can edit_posts and assign show_in_menu based on that.

```
class Admin_Menu_Page {
    const MENU_SLUG = 'my-menu-slug';
    // ...
    public static function get_CPT_show_in_menu() {
        if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
            $result = self::MENU_SLUG;
        } else {
            $result = TRUE;
        }
        return $result;
    }
    public static function create_menu() {
        if ( self::get_CPT_show_in_menu() === self::MENU_SLUG ) {
            // Create my custom menu page
        }
    }
}

class My_CPT {
    const POST_TYPE = 'my-post-type';
    // ...
    public static function register() {
        $args = array(
            // ...
            'show_in_menu'    => Admin_Menu_Page::get_CPT_show_in_menu(),
            // ...
        );
        register_post_type( self::POST_TYPE, $args );
    }
}
```

Comment: Very elegant.  This works, but still breaks when a custom capability is used (like `edit_my_post_type`) in place of `edit_post`.

Comment: Yes, the bug is specific to the `edit_posts` capability so that's what you have to check when determining the correct setting for `show_in_menu`.  But you can still register the post types with custom capabilities as you would normally.  In fact, this is what I do.

Answer (score -1):

I came across this some time ago, I'll try to find time to correctly debug the origin of the issue but in the meantime, try this:

```
/*
This is due to a bug that doesn't grant permission to the post-new.php unless there is a
submenu with the link accesible for the user.
*/
global $submenu;
$submenu['your_menu'][] = array(
    'Hide me', # Do something to hide it or just leave it blank.
    'create_posts',
    'post-new.php?post_type=your_post_type',
);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just got done tracing the core, and ... well, you're really close!  Answer to come!